# How do you draw complex, deeply nested scenes on HTMLCanvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Im my mario-like platformer game I draw everything on a canvas. There is a TV display which you can kick around. When drawing stuff on the TV screen I want to draw it as if the top left corner of the screen is (0; 0) but the TV itself is always rotated and translated. The problem gets worse if there are even deeper nested elements. Is there a framework or something which would help? How do you draw nested scenes? Or is this something not suitable for HTML5?

You may suggest to turn the TV into a separate canvas, rotate and translate it using HTML. But that's not going to work if I need to put some of the things in the game behind the TV and some of them in front. Unless I make each entity into a separate canvas. In which case there will be hundreds. That's probably a bad idea, right?

I already use a separate canvas for background, UI etc. But there is still quite a few entities which can appear both behind and in front of the TV.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations). For example, if you have a function `draw()` that draws something onto the canvas, you can do something like this

```
function draw(){
    //draw something on the canvas
}

ctx.translate(100,150);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/4);
ctx.scale(0.5,0.5);
draw();
```

and the content will be rendered rotated by 45 degrees, with the top left corner appearing at (100;150), and at half its normal size. To reset the transformation, simply call

```
ctx.resetTranform();
draw();
```

and everything will be drawn as normal again.
There is however a downside to this; the content is not clipped, so if `draw` renders something that would be otherwise offscreen, it will be displayed outside of the area you wanted it to be in.